# The importance of staying central in a visit to Amsterdam with car

Tags: road-trips, amsterdam

For a group of people driving to Amsterdam to stay for a few days with the following diversified agenda:

- Visiting tourist attractions
- Relaxing:

  - Enjoying the summer weather
  - Visiting bars and cafés during the day
- Night life:

  - Excessive consumption of alcohol
  - Consumption of enjoyable substances other than alcohol
  - Spurring some action in bars and clubs

how important is it that they find somewhere central to stay? Keep in mind that a car is in their hands (although it might be hard to drive when everybody is drunk during the night).

Exploring various places to stay with a price-limit in mind, I found two places for the same price:

- **First place:** Extremely central, but the quality could be better. Furthermore, the car needs to be parked somewhere - finding a parking spot in central Amsterdam is probably not an easy task.
- **Second place:** 10-15 km from the heart of Amsterdam, but it is extremely luxurious. The apartment also has parking spots.

Some points to consider:

- How hard is it to find a place to park the car in central Amsterdam?
- With the agenda of the group of people in mind, do they *have to* spend their time in the city's center or is there plenty to do across all of Amsterdam?
- How are taxis and public transport in Amsterdam?

There are probably important points that have slipped my mind.

Comment: There are many people from the Amsterdam here, so they will write a proper answer. I can recommend Zeeburg area (5km from central). That is where I stay. The metro is not very near, but there are tram lines all night. Plenty of parking options too. If you can mention what are your choices so far, I think others will make good recommendations.

Comment: Given your planned activities, why is this even a question?  You should not be driving.  You don't have to stay in the centre; you can stay outside and take the very good public transport or a taxi.

Answer (score 5):

Finding a place to park isn't very hard, due to the prices of parking - this greatly discourages bringing your car into Amsterdam city centre. The standard solution is to park at one of the ["P+R"](http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/visiting/plan-your-trip/getting-around/parking/park-and-ride) parking garages at the edge of town and take public transport from there. This is *far* cheaper. (Can be as low as EUR 1/day!)

It might not be obvious to foreigners, but Amsterdam is merely the biggest city in a whole cluster of cities ("Randstad") in the West of the Netherlands, a cluster that's about as big as London. There's not just good public transport within Amsterdam, there are 24 hour train links to the neighboring cities. You can definitely visit those as well.